# ssl/tls jabber web client

Tags: ssl, xmpp

Does anyone know of a web-based (ie flash, java, etc) jabber client that supports SSL connections, either via socket or http-bind?  Preferably http-bind, but I'll take what I can get at this point.

I've tried jwchat and sparkweb, and neither of them seem to communicate properly.

Answer (score 2):

[SparkWeb](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp#sparkweb) by default doesn't do SSL or TLS, but the Red5 version does support it. It's described [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/docs/DOC-1553). You'll want to scroll down to the "TLS Support" section. The description talks about supporting SSL on the dedicated port 5223, as well as supporting it over HTTP-Bind on port 7443 with a plugin to Openfire. I don't know if the plain port 5223 support will work with a Jabber server other than OpenFire, though.

I haven't used the Red5 version, but I have used the stock version, and it works well enough. I don't think I'd want to use it as my day to day Jabber client, but in a pinch it does the job.

Comment: i totally forgot about that, as it wasnt working for unencrypted access (i think now due to a config issue).  thanks for reminding me.